# How to group content and add it to ArrayList as one object?

Tags: java, swing, oop, arraylist

I have several swing component declared in my GUI design. I have successfully converted most the components into String format shown below:

```
String NameOfCruise = Cruisename.getText().trim(); //JTextField
String startLValue = startL.getSelectedItem().toString(); //JComboBox
String endLValue = endL.getSelectedItem().toString();  // JComboBox
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(model1.getValue())); //JSpinner
String Shipname = ShipList.getSelectedValue().toString(); // JList
```

The purpose of the components above is to construct a form which allows the user to add a new Cruise to the system. After obtaining all the form input above, I want to store it into an ArrayList.

```
 ArrayList Cruise = new ArrayList();
```

However, I want to store it in this format:

```
Cruise Name: ________
Start Port: _________
End Port: _______
Start Date: _________
End Date: _______
Assigned to ship: ______
```

So that if I have the option to list all the cruises in the system, it displays it as one object. For example if I have one Cruise in the ArrayList, it will display all the details assigned to it as well.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Read up on encapsulation and Object Oriented principles.

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing data with its representation. I imagine that you'll be storing Cruise objects within your `ArrayList<Cruise>`, and all this holds is pure data including Strings, Dates, etc, and this should be part of your program's *Model*. How it is displayed will be up to your GUI or the *View*. If you wanted to display a `List<Cruise>` in the format you mentioned, you could do so in a JList for instance, and have the cell renderer return a JPanel with the appropriate fields filled in with the individual Cruise's attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use correct data representation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Cruise> cruiseList = new ArrayList<Cruise>();
    cruiseList.add(new Cruise("Cruise 1", "Florida", "Puerto Rico", new Date(), new Date(), "Captain X"));
    System.out.println(cruiseList.get(0));
}

private static class Cruise {
    private String name;
    private String startPort;
    private String endPort;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private String assignedToShip;

    public Cruise(String name, String startPort, String endPort, Date startDate, Date endDate, String assignedToShip) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.startPort = startPort;
        this.endPort = endPort;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.assignedToShip = assignedToShip;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Cruise Name: ").append(name).append("\n");
        sb.append("Start Port: ").append(startPort).append("\n");
        sb.append("End Port: ").append(endPort).append("\n");
        sb.append("Start Date: ").append(startDate).append("\n");
        sb.append("End Date: ").append(endDate).append("\n");
        sb.append("Assigned to ship: ").append(assignedToShip).append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStartPort() {
        return startPort;
    }

    public void setStartPort(String startPort) {
        this.startPort = startPort;
    }

    public String getEndPort() {
        return endPort;
    }

    public void setEndPort(String endPort) {
        this.endPort = endPort;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public String getAssignedToShip() {
        return assignedToShip;
    }

    public void setAssignedToShip(String assignedToShip) {
        this.assignedToShip = assignedToShip;
    }
}
```